# Handling software updates in Docker images

Tags: docker, auto-update, apt, package-managers

Let's say I create a docker image called `foo` that contains the apt package `foo`. `foo` is a long running service inside the image, so the image isn't restarted very often. What's the best way to go about updating the package inside the container?

I could tag my images with the version of `foo` that they're running and install a specific version of the package inside the container (i.e. `apt-get install foo=0.1.0` and tag my container `foo:0.1.0`) but this means keeping track of the version of the package and creating a new image/tag every time the package updates. I would be perfectly happy with this if there was some way to automate it but I haven't seen anything like this yet.

The alternative is to install (and update) the package on container startup, however that means a  varying delay on container startup depending on whether it's a new container from the image or we're starting up an existing container. I'm currently using this method but the delay can be rather annoying for bigger packages.

What's the (objectively) best way to go about handling this? Having to wait for a container to start up and update itself is not really ideal.

Answer (score 6):

If you need to update something in your container, you need to build a new container. Think of the container as a statically compiled binary, just like you would with C or Java. Everything inside your container is a dependency. If you have to update a dependency, you recompile and release a new version.

If you tamper with the contents of the container at startup time you lose all the benefits of Docker: That you have a traceable build process and each container is verifiably bit-for-bit identical everywhere and every time you copy it.

Now let's address *why* you need to update `foo`. The only reason you should have to update a dependency outside of the normal application delivery cycle is to patch a security vulnerability. If you have a CVE notice that ubuntu just released a security patch then, yep, you have to rebuild every container based on ubuntu.

There are several services that scan and tell you when your containers are vulnerable to published CVEs. For example, [Quay.io](https://blog.quay.io/quay-secscanner-clair1/) and [Docker Hub](https://docs.docker.com/docker-cloud/builds/image-scan/) scan containers in your registry. You can also do this yourself using [Clair](https://github.com/coreos/clair), which Quay uses under the hood.

For any other type of update, just don't do it. Docker is a 100% fossilization strategy for your application and the OS it runs on.

Because of this your Docker container will work even if you copy it to 1000 hosts with slightly different library versions installed, or run it alongside other containers with different library versions installed. You container will continue to work 2 years from now, even if the dependencies can no longer be downloaded from the internet.

If for some reason you *can't* rebuild the container from scratch (e.g. it's already 2 years old and all the dependencies went missing) then yes, you *can* download the container, run it interactively, and update dependencies. Do this in a shell and then publish a new version of your container back into your registry and redeploy. Don't do this at startup time.

Comment: Well the reason for updating `foo` is that it's usually better to be on the latest version of a service, especially ones that prompt you if your version is out of date. I didn't know you should treat containers as static entities but it makes sense. I'll take a look at automating the creation of containers with static versions and tags, thanks!